# Adding data to FlatList clears the whole list

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I have a flatlist, that takes data from "state". This works. Then, I added a new function in order to add new data to the flatlist (additionally to the existing data).

As soon as I click on the "delete" button ( don't mind the name) the data of the flatlist is being deleted completely. I want the output to be like

Object 1

Object 2

Object 3 (has been added after button click)

What am I doing wrong? Can you please explain me the reason?

**EDIT: I get this warning, but no error.**

> VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or
> id property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor.,

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    initialElements: [
      { id: "0", text: "Object 1" },
      { id: "1", text: "Object 2" },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    const currentCounter = this.state.counter;
    const exampleState = this.state.initialElements;

    const addElement = () => {
      let newArray = [...exampleState, { id: "2", text: "Object 3" }];
      this.setState({
        initialElements: [newArray],
      });
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.counter}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{currentCounter}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.deleteButton}>
          <Button
            title="Hello"
            onPress={() =>
              this.setState({
                counter: currentCounter + 1,
              })
            }
          ></Button>
          <View style={styles.space}></View>
          <Button title="Delete" onPress={addElement}></Button>{" "}
          {/* as soon as I click here, the content of the list is being deleted */}
        </View>

        <FlatList
          style={styles.listStyle}
          key={(item) => item.id}
          data={exampleState}
          renderItem={(item) => <Text>{item.item.text}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  counter: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  deleteButton: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    margin: 5,
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  space: {
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
  },
  textStyle: {
    margin: 80,
    fontSize: 100,
  },

  listStyle: {
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the addElement to function to:

```
const addElement = () => {
      var newArray = [...exampleState, {id : 2, text : "Object 3"}];
      this.setState( {
        initialElements: newArray
      });
}
```

So, basically I changed

```
initialElements: [newArray]
```

to

```
initialElements: newArray
```

because newArray is already an Array, so no need to wrap it again.